# Raspberry pi - Deluge - Port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi that I use as an always on torrent client(cheap and easy). The pi is connected to a hard drive that is shared over my network.

Now someone told me that port forwarding helps increase speeds of up/downloads.So i did that. But now i wonder how safe is this port forwarding (I use Deluge as torrent client). And does this make the pc's in my network vulnerable to attacks?

Ps. The port I forwarded is just random port up in the 50 K range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading this:

http://www.techsupportalert.com/optimizing-deluge-speed

You seem to have the right idea.  Using a random port in the right range helps to make you less susceptible to attack.

Comment: I guess i took the wrong stackexchange...